# Automatic agricultural robot using 8051

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, robotics, 8051

I want to build a automatic agricultural robot for my final year diploma project. The basic idea is to program 8051 to drive the robot in a fixed path in farm for ploughing the farm which i am planning to do by setting a particular distance till which it will go straight and then take a U turn and plough in next lane. Width of the farm will also be set so when it completes full farm it'll stop and go back to starting point. the only catch is to reprogram it as per size of the farm of the person who uses it. So i want to add a number pad with which he can set the length and width of the farm as well as width of each lane as per his needs without professional help. Can this be done using 8051 or should i go for AVR or PIC microcontrollers. I have just started studying programming and interfacing of 8051 so I am not that good in programming. If its possible how do i do it. can someone please help me with circuit diagram for this project. After everything i said i need in my project if i still get an empty port in microcontroller I would love to add a fertilizer sprayer or water irrigation system and a GSM module so that a farmer can simply ask the robot to start working using his mobile phone. As I am making just a prototype i want it to be as small as possible. Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: What you describe would take a lot of work. Perhaps a year for a small team to get a functioning prototype. Since you are inexperienced with little programming knowledge, you would not get very far. I say this as someone who works at a university and supervises small teams of students on projects.

Comment: Closing due to crossposting.  See http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/1781/624

Comment: @Grinch - it's not Christmas time yet. Closing on one site would be enough (as you know). This seems the better site t o retain it on. .

Comment: Most of us would not choose an 8051 in this day and age, but that is beside the point: your proposal to use dead reckoning navigation will be unacceptably off after a few rows, and that for a model on an even floor, rather than a tractor in a field.

Comment: @Russell: Closing on both sites is so that the OP doesn't get what he came here for.  There needs to be something to lose by flaunting the rules.

Comment: Here's an idea out of the left (presumably unploughed) field: tether your ploughing machine to a central post with a retractable cord, start ploughing in almost any direction until the desired radius is reached, turn 90 degrees and plough in ever decreasing "circles" until done. With a bit of thought, even a rectangular field could be ploughed in this fashion. The problem devolves to measuring the angle and distance to the central post.

Answer (score 2):

What you need, friend is simply a proof of concept.

Step 1- Put down the 8051 and forget about it - go get an off the shelf arduino. You will run out of time building it in and debugging it. Only go back to it if your professor insists that arduino is too easy.

Step 2 - Go build the arduino into a rolling platform. This has been done so many ways, you'll have an easy time finding one - maybe even in a kit.

Step 3 - Add an off the shelf GSM shield  kit, put in a reliable prepaid sim card, and start debugging that.

Step 4 - Add LEDs to whatever digital pins you have left. Write code into your controller that makes them flash at defined points in the run. Call it the "fertilizer function".

Step 5 - Present the heck out of it. Make the presentation a sales pitch and exude confidence. Be able to answer all the questions intelligently - this is more important than actually making the thing turn circles and light up.

Step 6 (optional) - Get serious about this idea, follow up on all the loose ends, find investors and build it until someone buys you out.

Comment: +1 for step 5; quite a lot of coursework is marked on the basis of the presentation more than the underlying work.

Comment: It's been my observation that people that build their entire capstone project around an Arduino and shields are just masking the fact they don't know jack, and prolonging the inevitable.

Comment: Its been my observation that people who avoid simplification brought on by new formats and technologies are prone to saying "back in my day..." and prolonging the inevitable.

Comment: @SeanBoddy I'll let the guys that graduated with me that are working in pizza places and temp agencies know that.

Comment: @MattYoung, I get it, I really do. But one day someone will build the thing that obviates our entire field and makes the flow of tacit knowledge trivial. Its probably sitting in a google project document. devansh, don't let a bundled programmer/microcontroller/software package make you lazy about the issues!

Comment: I remain immensely puzzled by the raw hatred that Arduino's seem to generate in otherwise sometimes sane people. An Arduino is just a tool, and if it has managed to  simplify certain areas of the field to the extent that they are trivial then they always were trivial and the old tools were rubbish and the high priests are jealous. However, if , as is more likely, the Arduino has simply made the trivial entrance way more accessible and the great and holy embedded monolith is just as challenging as ever once you get past the intro, then the arduino is doing great service by bringing people ....

Comment: Into the entrance hall so they can better see what its al about.| Aka - get over it, take advantage of the  influx of new minds, Enjoy ... .

Comment: An Arduino would make sense if the poster were starting from scratch, but they seem to have momentum in the 8051 direction.  Neither (no computer on its own) will solve the issue of dead reckoning navigation that will limit this project even if the implementation is otherwise perfect.

Comment: @Russell: This is a school project, so the point is to learn something, not to get a proof of concept up and running quickly.  Arduinos may make sense for the latter, but defeat the purpose of the former since they are specifically designed to hide underlying implementation details that someone studying in that field needs to know.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, agreed - onboard land nav isnt really going to work on this kind of project. I just remember my graduating year project and my team, and the other project with the other team, and the other one after that - i mean holy cow. Sure if the 8051 is already broken out and ready to program - absolutely, no reason not to. But if you havent even purchased it, or gained access to it, at LEAST try to get a breakout board.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is certainly within the capabilities of readily available off the shelf microcontrollers.  Note that Intel, the originator of the 8051 architecture, has discontinued it.  There are still some clones available from other companies, but it's not something I'd use in a new design.  There are plenty of sufficiently capable microcontrollers available from Microchip, Atmel, TI, Freescale, and others, that are in active production.

One important issue you seem to be ignoring is navigation.  Just going out and back by driving the wheels in what should be a straight line is nowhere near good enough to eventually cover a whole field on a practical farm.  You will need some kind of position sensing and the robot adjusting its direction according to where it is and where it wants to be.

I have heard of one project doing this with real commercial farm equipment by using differential GPS.  That is neither easy nor cheap, and I think too much for a 4th year EE project.

You might be able to do simple navigation by following a laser beam.  Or, maybe use ordinary GPS to show that you are doing navigation.  Don't pretend this will solve the problem on a real farm, but for demonstrating that you've built a whole system and learned something in the process it might be good enough.

Comment: Info only: At one stage (20+ years ago?) I repaired some "tractor radars" for a friend. These were doppler radar units pointing forward at an angle to measure ground speed when the tractor was plowing in high wheel slip conditions. This was prior to GPS being readily available (or prior to GPS?). The units were "waterproof" but not "WATERPROOF!" in farm conditions and repairs was mainly salvaging and rebuilding what one could  from water damaged units. I don't recall the now long ago details but suspect that the replacements were so vastly expensive as to make such repair worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting in the wrong place. Selecting a processor for your robot is way down in the implementation details, and you haven't done a top-level system design yet.

You want to plow a field. What does it take to do that? First of all, you need to navigate parallel rows, which you've already identified, and you need to develop enough power to actually do the plowing.

How accurate does the navigation need to be? What sorts of things are going to perturb your navigation? I'm talking about things like the uneven ground and the sideways forces generated by the plow. Since you can't predict those perturbations, you'll need some sort of feedback system to keep the plow on track. What kind of sensors will this require? GPS is one way to get absolute navigation data, but by itself, it isn't normally accurate enough for a task like plowing.

Plowing requires a great deal of power, which means that the robot could do some serious damage if its navigation fails, or it fails to recognize an unexpected obstruction, such as the farmer. How will you recognize obstructions and stop the system safely when unexpected conditions occur? Autonomous vehicles have traditionally (so far) used primarily optical sensors, such as LIDAR and machine vision (video cameras), both of which require considerable real-time computing resources.

The point I'm making is that for a complex system like this, you need to start with your top-level requirements, identify technological building blocks that will help you meet those requirements, and then work your way down to lower levels of detail as you address each of the blocks identified in the previous step.

At some point, you'll have a good idea of the computing resources required, and then you can start selecting a processor.

BTW, I'm speaking as someone who has actually helped build precision navigation systems for real farming equipment, so I have a very good idea of what's really required.